# Filtering a data frame in R and an unwanted filtered out result

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, subset

This snippet:

```
names<-c("Alice","Bob","Charlie")
ages<-c(25,24,25)
friends<-data.frame(names,ages)
a25 <- friends[friends$age==25,]
a25
table(a25$names)
```

gives me this output

```
    names ages
1   Alice   25
3 Charlie   25

  Alice     Bob Charlie 
      1       0       1
```

Now, why "Bob" is in the output since the data frame `a25` does not include "Bob"? I would expected an output like this (from the `table` command):

```
  Alice  Charlie 
      1        1
```

What am I missing?

My environment:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

Comment: Your `names` variable has been converted to a factor. And `table` shows the counts of every level of your factor, even if they have 0 count.

Comment: @juba Thanks, and so when I create the `a25` variable, does it "inherit" the factor with three levels?

Comment: `a25` is not a variable, it is a data frame which is a subset of `friends`. So it inherits the `age` factor from `friends` with all its levels, yes.

Comment: @juba OK, I understand. Is it possible to get result I was expecting?

Comment: You can try `a25$age <- factor(a25$age)`. Or keep your variable as `character` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `data.frame`.

Comment: @juba OK, thank you. It seems to work with `a25$names <- factor(a25$names)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question appears to have an answer in the comments. This answer shares one additional approach and consolidates the suggestions from the comments.

The problem you describe is as follows: There is no "Bob" in your "a25$names" variable, but when you use `table`, "Bob" shows up. This is because the levels present in the original column have been retained.

```
table(a25$names)
# 
#   Alice     Bob Charlie 
#       1       0       1
```

Fortunately, there's a function called `droplevels` that takes care of situations like this:

```
table(droplevels(a25$names))
# 
#   Alice Charlie 
#       1       1
```

The `droplevels` function can work on a `data.frame` too, allowing you to do the following:

```
a25alt <- droplevels(friends[friends$ages==25,])
a25alt
#     names ages
# 1   Alice   25
# 3 Charlie   25
table(a25alt$names)
# 
#   Alice Charlie 
#       1       1
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, also look at `as.character` and `factor`:

```
table(as.character(a25$names))
table(factor(a25$names))
```